# How to replace environment variables using ansible

Tags: ansible

I am automating my DevOps tasks using ansible. On my remote machine, I have a configuration file which I use for different tasks.

The `env.conf` file has following content

```
IP=192.168.1.100
PORT=5250

#Other details here
```

What I want to do it replace IP value `192.168.1.100` and port values '5250' to some other values

```
IP=NEW_IP
PORT=NEW_PORT

#Other details here
```

How can I achieve this using ansible-playbook file?

I know of ansible file module but how to replace the content of environment variables using ansible-playbook file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [Ansible module lineinfile](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html). As a playbook you could use the following:

```
- hosts: all
  vars:
    new_ip: 1.1.1.1
    new_port: 1234
  tasks:
    - file:
        path: /etc/env.conf
        state: touch
    - name: Substitute ip
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/enc.conf
        regexp: '^IP='
        line: 'IP={{ new_ip }}'
    - name: Substitute port
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/env.conf
        regexp: '^PORT='
        line: 'PORT={{ new_port }}'
```

Comment: Perfect. The only thing that is short in this approach is if the file does not exist, it throws an error.  It should have created the file if it did not exist.

Comment: I tried to keep the answer small and a not existant file was not part of your question.

Comment: Yeah you are right. But is there a way it will create file if not exist?

Comment: I editted the code above to get the file created if not existant.

Comment: perfect. Thanks. can we can set IP and Port value in one task or in the same task.
Currently, we have two separate task for the same

Comment: Not in a way that it makes sense. You could theoretically use module blockinfile, but that's quite hacky.

Comment: ok, 100 upvotes  to your help